# Add service reference to metadata WebService in CRM 2011

Tags: web-services, iis, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-4

I need to connect to the metadata WebService provided by CRM 2011.
I do know it is there just for compatibility issues and that I should not use it.

Still, I need to do it.

When I add the url of the web service I get his error:

There was an error downloading [link](https://lll.ppp/mscrmservices/2007/metadataservice.asmx?WSDL&uniquename=orgname/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/%24metadata).
The request failed with the error message:

```HTML
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Object moved</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Object moved to 
            <a href="https://lll.ppp/mscrmservices/2007/metadataservice.asmx?   
            WSDL&uniquename=orgname/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata">here</a>.
       </h2>
    </body>
</html>


Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
 'https://lll.ppp/mscrmservices/2007/metadataservice.asmx?WSDL&uniquename=orgname'.
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. 
The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'.
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
If the service is defined in the current solution, 
try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

I checked and anonymous authentication is enabled.
What is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the IP address solved it.